# Sorting a frequency matrix by weekday sequence in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, frequency

I am doing some exploratory stuff on a data set that includes certain transactions.

Every row represents a transaction with a specific date. I want to produce a frequency matrix of transactions for the different weekdays.

```
table(weekdays(x$date))
```

This is working but the weekdays are in alphabetical order `(e.g. Mo, Fr, Sa, Tu..)` instead of logical order `(Mo, Tu, We..)`.

Anybody knows how to fix that easily? Or do I have to factorize the result?

Best wishes,
Marcus

Comment: Using `factor` would probably be your best bet here, you could also do `table(...)[c(1,4, ...)]` if you know the order in which `R` is supplying the names

Comment: More specifically: `wkdays <- c('Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa','Su');set.seed(123);x <- table(sample(wkdays, 1000, T));x[c(2, 6, 7, 5, 1, 3, 4)]`

Comment: Reordering as above or you could build it from a date sequence: `daysOrdered <- weekdays(seq(as.Date("2017-1-2"), length.out=7, by="day"))` then `table(...)[daysOrdered]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `factor`:

```
# oldlocale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
# Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english")
table(factor(
  weekdays(Sys.Date()+0:7), 
  levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
))
   # Monday   Tuesday Wednesday  Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday 
   #      1         1         1         1         2         1         1 
# Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", oldlocale)
```

Comment: Just being pedantic, but Sunday is the first day of the week.

Comment: Feel free to adjust/debate it. ;-)